How to fix "nothing to install, update or remove" when installing PHPCompatibility with Composer?
I think I'm missing something. The instructions for PHPCompatibility say to create the following composer.json file:
{
    "require-dev": {
    "phpcompatibility/php-compatibility": "*"
},
"prefer-stable" : true,
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": "\"vendor/bin/phpcs\" --config-set installed_paths vendor/phpcompatibility/php-compatibility",
    "post-update-cmd" : "\"vendor/bin/phpcs\" --config-set installed_paths vendor/phpcompatibility/php-compatibility"
    }
}

Then it says, "Run composer update --lock to install both PHP CodeSniffer, the PHPCompatibility coding standard and - optionally - the Composer plugin."
When I do that I get, "nothing to install, update or remove".  Then I tried installing the way I have in the past, with, "composer install", which seemed to work, but gave a warning, "No composer.lock file present. Updating dependencies to latest instead of installing from lock file." So what is the right way to do this?

It might be something with cache. Remove composer.lock and vendor dir and run composer install or composer update and provide output here.

"The instructions for PHPCompatibility say to create the following composer.json file" - what does that mean? Did your project include any composer.json before? If this is the case, you should add the parts to the existing file instead of creating a new one

I solved this by ignoring the instructions in the php-compatibility readme and following the ones here instead: https://cu.be/a-comprehensive-guide-to-using-phpcompatibility-in-your-project/. Specifically these instructions, which were clear and made sense to me, and worked perfectly:
before_script:
  - composer require --dev squizlabs/php_codesniffer
  - composer require --dev phpcompatibility/php-compatibility
  - vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths vendor/phpcompatibility/php-compatibility
script:
  - vendor/bin/phpcs /path/to/your/code --standard=PHPCompatibility --extensions=php

